# Creating new columns from existing column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
data = [['A', 1, 100], ['A', 3, 100], ['A', 2, 100], ['A', 3, 100], ['A', 5, 100]]
df =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['?', 'Rating', 'Amount'])
```

```
    ?   Rating  Amount
0   A   1       100
1   A   3       100
2   A   2       100
3   A   3       100
4   A   5       100
```

and I need to create new columns based on the Rating value substituting in the amount - looks something like this:

```
    ?   Rating  Amount  1   2   3   5
0   A   1       100     100 0   0   0
1   A   3       100     0   0   100 0
2   A   2       100     0   100 0   0
3   A   3       100     0   0   100 0
4   A   5       100     0   0   0   100
```

Right now I have this:

```
ratingnames = np.unique(list(df['Rating']))
ratingnames.sort()

d = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(df['Rating'])), columns=ratingnames)

for i in range(len(df['Rating'])):
    ratingvalue = df.loc[i, 'Rating']
    d.loc[i, ratingvalue] = df.loc[i, 'Amount']

df = pd.concat([df, d], axis = 1)
```

but I feel like it could be improved upon. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and multiply with `df['Amount'],` then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on `axis=1`:

```
output = pd.concat((df,pd.get_dummies(df['Rating']).mul(df['Amount'],axis=0)),axis=1)
```

---

```
   ?  Rating  Amount    1    2    3    5
0  A       1     100  100    0    0    0
1  A       3     100    0    0  100    0
2  A       2     100    0  100    0    0
3  A       3     100    0    0  100    0
4  A       5     100    0    0    0  100
```

Timings:
[image]

Comment: @ecaines You should not use `apply` when not required in pandas especially `axis=1` is very slow. Added some timing test to demonsrate what I meant

Comment: interesting, thanks for adding that in. very helpful

Comment: @ecaines no problem ..happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```py
df=pd.concat([df, df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({x["Rating"]: x["Amount"]}), axis=1).fillna(0).astype("int")], axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
   ?  Rating  Amount    1    2    3    5
0  A       1     100  100    0    0    0
1  A       3     100    0    0  100    0
2  A       2     100    0  100    0    0
3  A       3     100    0    0  100    0
4  A       5     100    0    0    0  100
```